# How to create a reusable 'Contains' expression for EF Core

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-core, linq-expressions

### Problem

I need to execute a partial text search, alongside other filters, via a generic repository using expressions.

### State of current code

I have a generic method that returns paged results from my database (via a common repository layer).

In the following working example;

- `PagedRequest` contains the current pagesize and page number, and is used during respective `Skip` / `Take` operations.
- `PagedResult` contains a collection of the results, along with the total number of records.

```cs
public Task<PagedResult<Person>> GetPeopleAsync(PersonSearchParams searchParams,
    PagedRequest pagedRequest = null)
{
    ParameterExpression argParam = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Locum), "locum");

    // start with a "true" expression so we have an expression to "AndAlso" with
    var alwaysTrue = Expression.Constant(true);
    var expr = Expression.Equal(alwaysTrue, alwaysTrue);

    if (searchParams != null)
    {
        BinaryExpression propExpr;

        if (searchParams.DateOfBirth.HasValue)
        {
            propExpr = GetExpression(searchParams.DateStart,
                nameof(Incident.IncidentDate), 
                argParam, 
                ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual);

            expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, propExpr);
        }

        if (searchParams.DateOfDeath.HasValue)
        {
            propExpr = GetExpression(searchParams.DateEnd,
                nameof(Incident.IncidentDate), 
                argParam, 
                ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual);

            expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, propExpr);
        }

        if (searchParams.BranchId.HasValue && searchParams.BranchId.Value != 0)
        {
            propExpr = GetExpression(searchParams.BranchId, 
                nameof(Incident.BranchId), argParam);

            expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, propExpr);
        }
    }

    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Locum, bool>>(expr, argParam);
    return _unitOfWork.Repository.GetAsync(filter: lambda, pagedRequest: pagedRequest);
}
```

This is using my static `GetExpression` method for `Expression.Equal`, `Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual` and `Expression.LessThanOrEqual` queries as follows;

```cs
private static BinaryExpression GetExpression<TValue>(TValue value,
    string propName, ParameterExpression argParam, ExpressionType? exprType = null)
{
    BinaryExpression propExpr;

    var prop = Expression.Property(argParam, propName);
    var valueConst = Expression.Constant(value, typeof(TValue));

    switch (exprType)
    {
        case ExpressionType.GreaterThanOrEqual:
            propExpr = Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(prop, valueConst);
            break;
        case ExpressionType.LessThanOrEqual:
            propExpr = Expression.LessThanOrEqual(prop, valueConst);
            break;
        case ExpressionType.Equal:
        default:// assume equality
            propExpr = Expression.Equal(prop, valueConst);
            break;
    }
    return propExpr;
}
```

NOTE: this code is working correctly.

### Problem

Using example from other SO answers I have tried the following;

#### Expressions

I have tried getting the contains via an `Expression`;

```cs
static Expression<Func<bool>> GetContainsExpression<T>(string propertyName, 
    string propertyValue)
{
    var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
    var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
    MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var someValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
    var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<bool>>(containsMethodExp);
}
```

This has to be converted to a `BinaryExpression` so it can be added to the expression tree using `AndAlso`. I've tried to compare the `Expression` with a `true` value, but this isn't working

```cs
if (searchParams.FirstName.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    var propExpr = GetContainsExpression<Locum>(nameof(Locum.Firstname), 
        searchParams.FirstName);

    var binExpr = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, propExpr, propExpr);
    expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, binExpr);
}
```

#### MethodCallExpression

I also tried returning the `MethodCallExpression` (instead of the Lambda above), using the following;

```cs
static MethodCallExpression GetContainsMethodCallExpression<T>(string propertyName, 
    string propertyValue)
{
    var parameterExp = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "type");
    var propertyExp = Expression.Property(parameterExp, propertyName);
    MethodInfo method = typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains", new[] { typeof(string) });
    var someValue = Expression.Constant(propertyValue, typeof(string));
    var containsMethodExp = Expression.Call(propertyExp, method, someValue);

    return containsMethodExp;
}
```

I used this as follows;

```cs
if (searchParams.FirstName.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    var propExpr = GetContainsMethodCallExpression<Person>(nameof(Person.FirstName), 
        searchParams.FirstName);

    var binExpr = Expression.MakeBinary(ExpressionType.Equal, propExpr, alwaysTrue);
    expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, binExpr);
}
```

#### Exceptions

These expression are passed to a generic method that pages information out of the database, and the exceptions are thrown during the first execution of the query when I *Count* the total matching number of record on the constructed `query`.

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(p => True && p.FirstName.Contains("123") == True)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable ', 'AsAsyncEnumerable ', 'ToList ', or 'ToListAsync '. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

This exception is thrown on a `Count` method I am using in my paging code. This code is already working without any filters, and with the `ExpressionType` filters described at the top, so I haven't included this code as I don't believe it is relevant.

```cs
pagedResult.RowCount = query.Count();
```

Comment: In LINQ with EF Core there is a `EF.Functions.Contains` see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.contains Maybe you can make use of this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This has to be converted to a BinaryExpression so it can be added to the expression tree using `AndAlso`

Negative. There is no requirement `Expression.AndAlso` (or `Expression.OrElse`) *operands* to be binary expressions (it would have been strange like requiring left or right operand of `&&` or `||` to be always comparison operators). The only requirement is them to be `bool` returning expressions, hence *call* to string `Contains` is a perfectly valid operand expression.

So start by changing the type of the inner local variable from `BinaryExpression` to `Expression`:

```
if (searchParams != null)
{
    Expression propExpr;
    
    // ...
}
```

The same btw applies for the initial expression - you don't need `true == true`, simple
`Expression expr = Expression.Constant(true);` would do the same.

Now you could emit method call to `string.Contains` in a separate method similar to the other that you've posted (passing the `ParameterExpression` and building property selector expression) or inline similar to:

```
if (searchParams.FirstName.IsNotNullOrWhiteSpace())
{
    var propExpr = Expression.Property(argParam, nameof(Person.FirstName));
    var valueExpr = Expression.Constant(searchParams.FirstName);
    var containsExpr = Expression.Call(
        propExpr, nameof(string.Contains), Type.EmptyTypes, valueExpr);
    expr = Expression.AndAlso(expr, containsExpr);
}
```

Comment: This is great explanation, thanks for taking the time to respond :-)